# Interpreting data from crash dump using winDbg

Tags: wcf, windbg

I am trying to debug a WCF service which is crashing from time to time. I have created a crash dump file using adplus, that was the easy part, I used this command.

```
adplus.exe -crash -pmn myservicehost.exe -o c:\dump
```

I am opening the file .dmp file with winDbg x64 version 6.2.9200. When I look at the threads !Threads I see there are a bunch of threads that that are waiting for a callback to complete (I think).

```
0:031> ~~[1b00]s
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00000000`778d18ca c3              ret
0:029> ~~[1b00]s
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xa:
00000000`778d18ca c3              ret
```

Eventually it crashes. Here is the output when I look at the call stack from that exception using !PrintException /d -nested 00000002814ad6d0

```
Exception object: 00000002814af4c8
Exception type:   System.Runtime.CallbackException
Message:          A user callback threw an exception.  Check the exception stack and inner exception to determine the callback that failed.
InnerException:   System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException, Use !PrintException 00000002814ad6d0 to see more.
StackTrace (generated):
    SP               IP               Function
    000000000FA89D40 000007FEDD9AD3E2 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnClosed()+0x262
    000000000FA8C240 000007FEDD93759D System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnClosed()+0x6d
    000000000FA8C290 000007FEDD9433D0 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.OnClosed()+0x10
    000000000FA8C2C0 000007FEDE185B86 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Abort()+0x2b6
    000000000FA8C3C0 000007FE8ABAC89C MyCompany_WcfApp_WcfAppServiceHost!MyCompany.WcfApp.WcfAppServiceHost.WcfAppServiceHost.FaultedServiceHandler(System.Object, System.EventArgs)+0x26c
    000000000FA8C5F0 0000000000000000 mscorlib_ni!System.EventHandler.Invoke(System.Object, System.EventArgs)+0x1
    000000000FA8C5F0 000007FEDE184E9A System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()+0x1ca
    000000000FA8C670 000007FEDE184784 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()+0x94
    000000000FA8C6E0 000007FEDE184E9A System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()+0x1ca
    000000000FA8C760 000007FEDE184784 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()+0x94
    000000000FA8C7D0 000007FEDE184E9A System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.OnFaulted()+0x1ca
    000000000FA8C850 000007FEDE184784 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Fault()+0x94
    000000000FA8C8C0 000007FEDE475407 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.TryReceive(System.TimeSpan, System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message ByRef)+0x4f7
    000000000FA8EBF0 000007FEDE5409AE System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InputChannelBinder.TryReceive(System.TimeSpan, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext ByRef)+0x2e
    000000000FA8EC50 000007FEDEAC29E2 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.TryReceive(System.TimeSpan, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext ByRef)+0x646022
    000000000FA8ECB0 000007FEDE47C8D6 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TryTransactionalReceive(System.Transactions.Transaction, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext ByRef)+0x396
    000000000FA8ED70 000007FEDE47BE07 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.TransactedLoop()+0xb7
    000000000FA8EDF0 000007FEDE47BD31 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.SyncTransactionalMessagePump()+0x21
    000000000FA8EE20 000007FEDE47A829 System_ServiceModel_ni!System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnStartSyncMessagePump(System.Object)+0x209
    000000000FA8EED0 000007FEDB6DE651 System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler+ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x71
    000000000FA8EF30 000007FEDB77A260 System_ServiceModel_Internals_ni!System.Runtime.Fx+IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x9bcd0
    000000000FA8EF90 000007FEDF225C26 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+0x96
```

Problem is, this isn't really helping me. I need to find out what is creating all these locks. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might do that? I have never had an issue that required this level of debugging and to be honest I am not 100% sure what I am doing. If I haven't given enough info please let me know I will happily provide you with whatever else I can.

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried WCF Tracing?

Comment: No but I will look into for sure. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you showed the stack for exception object 00000002814af4c8, not 00000002814ad6d0. What does `!PrintException 00000002814ad6d0` show?

Comment: Actually I used WCF tracing is was way more informative and easier to see with the trace viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!SyncBlk` command of SOS to determine deadlocks if any.